# C: LINK.EXE fails from Makefile but not from the Command line

Tags: c, makefile, linker-errors, nmake

When I attempt to link from a makefile I get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'.
```

**Makefile Execution:**

```
C:\Users\snmcdonald\Desktop\winMake2\winMake2>nmake "_DEBUG=" /f win2.mk build

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /c /ZI /Fo"Debug\\" /Fe"Debug\\" main.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
        cl /c /ZI /Fo"Debug\\" /Fe"Debug\\" lib.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

lib.c
        lib Debug\lib.obj /out:Debug\lib.lib
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        link Debug\main.obj Debug\lib.lib /out:Debug\main.exe
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specif
ication
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BI
N\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
Stop.
```

However, if I rerun the exact same line that failed and link from the console I get a successful build. I am using the exact same `lib` and `obj` that were produced from my make file.

**Console Execution:**

```
C:\Users\snmcdonald\Desktop\winMake2\winMake2>link Debug\main.obj Debug\lib.lib /o
ut:Debug\main.exe
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specif
ication

C:\Users\SHANEM~1\Desktop\winMake2\winMake2>debug\main.exe
print from lib
```

I have included my makefile for reference.

**Makefile**

```
!ifdef _DEBUG
CC = cl
CFLAGS = /c /ZI
FILES = *.c 
OUT = /Fo"Debug\\" /Fe"Debug\\"
LINKOUT = /out:Debug
DIR = Debug
!else
CC = cl
CFLAGS = /O2
FILES = *.c 
OUT = /Fo"Release\\" /Fe"Release\\"
LINKOUT = /out:Release
DIR = Release
!endif

LIB = lib
LINK = link

RM = del
RMFLAGS = *.ojb *.exe 2>NUL

build: main.exe

clean:
    $(RM) $(RMFLAGS)

rebuild: clean build

main.exe: main.obj lib.lib
    $(LINK) $(DIR)\main.obj $(DIR)\lib.lib $(LINKOUT)\main.exe

lib.lib: lib.obj
    $(LIB) $(DIR)\lib.obj $(LINKOUT)\lib.lib

main.obj: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OUT) main.c

lib.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OUT) lib.c
```

**Testing**

I have tested this on both Visual C version 9 and version 10. I am confused why it would fail on my makefile but run successfully when manually entered on the command line.

**Solution:**

```
nmake /E /f win2.mk build
```

/E - overrides macro vars with environmental paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> LIB = lib

That screws up the LIB environment variable.  Yes, /E will fix it but your next project that actually needs lib.exe is going to fail.  Pick another name, win32.mak uses "implib".

Answer (score 1):

The file should exist in 
...\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\lib

It could be difference of environment variables setting. Check what are the enviroment variables setting when you run it manually from the command line.

http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/lnk1104-open-file-libcmt-lib-help-21575202.html

> The LIB environment variable should
>   contain the path to your various lib
>   directories. You can also run the
>   VCVARS32.BAT file, which will
>   automatically set the environment up
>   for you. If you do a lot of command
>   line builds, I recommend creating a
>   shortcut that invokes the above
>   mentioned VSVARS32.BAT

Comment: Some good points but I had no luck. I tried running VCVARS32.BAT inside my makefile, running VCVARS32BAT from the console, and I tried adding "/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib" as linker options.

Comment: Can you find that file in your disk ?

Comment: Yes: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" . In addition when I say console I mean the Visual Studio 2010 Prompt.